# How do I make each each element in array another array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some text that I receive from the user:

```
var text = ['Hello', 'World']; // this is the product of string.split(',')
```

I need to convert it into an array like this one:

```
var argument = [['Hello'], ['World']];
```

I  need the input in this format so I can send multiple values to the db.

How can I do this **elegantly**?

Comment: Checkout [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Please see #ninjagecko `Array.prototype.chunk` answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10456644/2365792). To use on your `text` array, do it like `var argument = text.chunk(text.length);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of anything more elegant for this than `map`:

E.g.:

```
var argument = originalString.split(",").map(function(entry) {
    return [entry];
});
```

Or if you've enabled ES6 on your NodeJS installation:

```
var argument = originalString.split(",").map((entry) => [entry]);
```

Comment: Perfect. How do I enable ES6 in Node? Are arrow functions supported yet?

Comment: @Angularnoob: Ah, looks like they aren't *quite* yet: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ES6-%28a.k.a.-Harmony%29-Features-Implemented-in-V8-and-Available-in-Node (right at the bottom, but I figured the page as a whole was useful to you).

Comment: @That is too bad, man. I am not much of a JS coder (evidently,) but it seems like ES 6 has been imminent for **ages**!

Comment: @Angularnoob: It's getting here. :-) About two years behind schedule, which isn't as bad as it could be as these things go...